# How do I create a heterogenous collection in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I would like to write the following data structure in Haskell:

```
Renderable a => [a] -- [ClassOne, ClassTwo, ClassThree]
```

where a `Renderable` is a type class

```
class Renderable a ...
```

and all of the concrete classes implement the type class

```
instance Renderable ClassOne ...
instance Renderable ClassTwo ...
instance Renderable ClassThree ...
```

---

A concrete example of this is writing a `World` class for a game engine.

```
data World a = World {
    -- ...
    wEntities :: [a]
}
```

This forces a homogenous list, however. I could write

```
{-# ExistentialQuantification #-}

data World = forall r. Renderable r => World {
    -- ...
    wEntities :: [r]
}
```

but I get the error

```
Record updates for insufficiently polymorphic fields
```

when writing

```
world { wEntities = fmap fn (wEntities world) }
```

---

Are there any alternatives that allow for a heterogenous collection based on a type class?

Comment: I suppose Google already gave you this article, but just in case: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need a list of `Renderable`s, you can use existentials for that.

```
class Renderable r where
   render :: r -> IO ()  -- dummy example

data R where
   R :: Renderable r => r -> R
-- or, if you prefer non-GADT syntax,
-- data R = forall r. Renderable r => r -> R

foo :: [R] -> IO ()
foo []         = return ()
foo (R r : rs) = render r >> foo rs
```

However, be careful since this extra complexity may not be needed, and sometimes leads to an [antipattern](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/).